# Debugging in visual studio takes 5-15 minutes per page(aspx)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, performance

I'm running a Pentium 4 2.8 ghz with 1.7g gigs of ram.

Comment: There is no way someone can come up with an answer unless you point out a lot of more info!

Comment: I think you want to ask something a bit more specific, like:
Why does it take so long to step through an aspx page (5-15 minutes), but I'm not sure, so I'll leave the editing to you.

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't answer that. You need to provide more information as to the actual problem you're having. Where is it slow, on compile, or stepping through, etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you add your files to IIS it wont take that time
run it from local host instead of debugging it from VS

Answer (score 1):

Have you any antivirus running on your machine?
If you have, try to disable it and debug your website again.